# JavaScript button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to using JavaScript so bear with me. I only finished the different courses found on Codecademy so far.

So I'm trying to make a sign up form for a website where you need a user. I found a pretty cool one on the internet that I changed a bit and also made use of the Datepicker from jQuery. It looks like this:

[image: Sign Up Form]

I got code to check whether the user filled out the different fields but it doesn't seem to work. In my `index.html` file I included the following file:

```
<script src="js/signupsubmit.js"></script>
```

And at the bottom of the form I do this:

```
<div>
    <p id="sign_user" onClick="Submit()">Sign Up</p>
</div>
```

So good so far. In the JavaScript I have the following code:

```
function Submit() {
    var emailRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._]*\@[A-Za-z]{2,5}$/;
    var fname = document.form.Name.value,
        lname = document.form.LastName.value,
        femail = document.form.Email.value,
        freemail = document.form.enterEmail.value,
        fpassword = document.form.Password.value,
        dateObject = $("#datepicker").datepicker(
        {
            onSelect: function()
            {
                var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            }
        });
    if( fname == "") {
        document.form.name.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Enter First Name";
        return false;
    }
    if( lname == "" )
    {
        document.form.LastName.focus() ;
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Enter Last Name";
        return false;
    }

    if (femail == "" )
    {
        document.form.Email.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Enter your Email Address";
        return false;
    }else if(!emailRegex.test(femail)){
        document.form.Email.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Enter a Valid Email Address";
        return false;
    }

    if (freemail == "" )
    {
        document.form.enterEmail.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Re-enter the Email Address";
        return false;
    }else if(!emailRegex.test(freemail)){
        document.form.enterEmail.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Re-enter a Valid Email Address";
        return false;
    }

    if(freemail !=  femail){
        document.form.enterEmail.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "The Email Addresses don't Match!";
        return false;
    }


    if(fpassword == "")
    {
        document.form.Password.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Enter a Password";
        return false;
    }

    if(dateObject == null) {
        document.form.datepicker.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Please Enter a Birthday";
    }
}
```

I am a bit shaky on trying to read the Datepicker too. But otherwise, can you possibly spot what might be missing in this puzzle? When I press the blue "Sign Up" button, literally nothing happens. I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: Did you open up the developer console and check for errors? Not sure why you would initialize the date picker after the person clicks the button. You should be initializing it outside of the submit method. And finally a `<p>` element is not going to submit a form.

Comment: You never call the form's submit function, ie `document.getElementById("myForm").submit()`

Comment: Try adding `return true;` to the end of the function, also you forgot a `return false;` in the last if statement. Edit: Also, your submit button should be a `<button type="submit">...`.

Comment: @epascarello Probably should have checked there first...well any way, it turns out I loaded Bootstrap.js before jQuery and that didn't fly so I switched the load order on that. But it also turns out I used invalid names for forms when looking up their values so the console also told me that. Thanks!

Comment: @epascarello Seems there is another issue though. I use the following line `fname = document.form.Name.value` and the console says there is no such thing. But in my HTML I use `<input type="text" name="Name" value="" placeholder="First Name" class="input_name">`. Wouldn't that be correct?

Comment: Is the form named form? `<form name="form">`

Comment: @epascarello I think I see the problem now. I have a <form> tag but I didn't place it right. Thanks again.

Comment: @Vipar - unrelated to your problem but ... your `emailRegex` is _*far*_ too simple and will exclude _huge_ numbers of valid email addresses (including one I use). There are horrendously long and complex regexes out on the net, but since you _must_ send an email to see if it's a real address you can be lax on your validation, and accept not-technically-valid addresses. I bring this up only because too many sites already tell me my actual email address is invalid and won't accept it.

Comment: @StephenP Any suggestions for a better regex?

Comment: @Vipar there's some discussion and regexes on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html), but personally I'd rather accept an invalid email than reject a valid one. If HTML5 is an option you can use `<input type="email">` and let the HTML5 validation do the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mistake addressing the form: The correct formula is not `document.form`, but `document.forms[0]`. Or even better, I recommend you to give the form a specific unique name, and address it by that name:

HTML:

```
<form name="mydata">...</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var fm=document.forms.mydata
```

Also, take care of lowercase/uppercase lettering: Identifiers in Javascript are *case-sensitive*, which means that the input "Name" must be always addressed as "Name" (you mispelled that identifier in the line `document.form.name.focus()`).